# Circuits for non existent devices

Tags: electrical, fuse, seat

My Honda Accord 2003 coupe (v6) came with optional Passenger’s Power Seat Recline and Passenger’s Power Seat Slide. I don't have these features, but I see the fuses in the fuse box are in place. These appear to be 20A fuses, could I use the existing fuse circuitry to power something else (like a power inverter)?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, but make sure that there are no other devices connected to those circuits - often the legend in the fuse box is for the major item due to a lack of space. The handbook may give more detail or the vehicle manual.

Edit: The owner's manual can give more detail compared to the lid of the fuse box, this image is from the Jaguar X-type owner's manual page 190, showing that one fuse may protect more than one circuit (the list of fuses goes on for another 2 pages...):

[image]

Comment: Good answer. Generally all the fuses and relays will come pre-installed in the box when it goes onto the assembly line, it's not worth someone's time pulling the components that aren't going to be used.

Comment: Thanks, what would I be looking for in the "handbook" (presuming you're referring to the repair manual?)?

Comment: @wizlog the handbook or owner’s manual usually gives a listing of fuses, circuits protected and fuse box locations so owners, who wish to, can replace fuses in an emergency.

Answer (score 0):

Here are more extensive fuse box images that may help determine what items are protected by a single fuse and wire colors.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Under Hood fuse box
[image]